# howto get the user id from a FormsAuthentication page in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

i made a webpage which use FormsAuthentication. now i need to get the user id of the user (if a user is logged in)

how to get these? i tryed to access it via the `FormsAuthentication` but there is no method liks: `getUserId()`

any solutions?
by the way, i need the id in my controller not in my view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    // Do stuf...
}
```

Comment: The "name" will be the id or username you store in the ticket when they sign in...